# How convert .tif to .mbtiles keeping projection using gdal

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I trying convert .tif using:

gdal_translate 4244.tif 4244.mbtiles -of MBTILES
gdaladdo -r average 4244.mbtiles 2 4 8 16

But, o file .mbtiles appear with diferent projection from origin file. Always convert to WG84?

Help me please!!!

Comment: That is naturally impossible because the only coordinate system that MBTiles support by the specification is web Mercator.

Comment: Use GeoPackage instead, it supports also other projections.